# How would I get this while loop to run the same thing as this for loop?

Tags: javascript

// Write your code below!

```
var iAmSoHungry = ["Salted Caramel Icecream","BLT","Pop's Potatoes","Chic Fila"];

var empty = [];

var answerToEverything = 42;


while(answerToEverything >38) {

    empty.push(iAmSoHungry[ "WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE TO GET THE SAME RESULT?"]);
    answertoEverything -= 1;
}


for(i=0;i<4;i++) {

    empty.push(iAmSoHungry[i]);
    console.log(empty);
}
```

Comment: i am not sure i am following you, what should be your end result?

Comment: The end result is I want to push the entirety of iAmSoHungry onto empty. The for loop works currently. Each iteration it pushes another (object?) of iAmSoHungry onto empty.

Comment: `var i=0; while(i++<4){ ...`

Answer (score 0):

`empty.push(iAmSoHungry[42 - answerToEverything]);` ?

On the first iteration of the `while` loop `answerToEverything` is 42, so you'll push `iAmSoHungry[0]` to `empty`. At each iteration of the loop you decrement `answerToEverything` so the result of `42 - answerToEverything` is incremented. In this way you'll consecutively add all elements of `iAmSoHungry` to `empty`.

The `for` loop below does the same, but using the iteration variable `i` to get the desired index instead of an expression.

You also have an error in the `while` loop: `answertoEverything` should be `answerToEverything` (the "to" capitalized).

Comment: It returned unexpected token, ILLEGAL.

Comment: I updated my answer, you have a typo. As for the error, it works for me, make sure you're using the correct minus sign.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why it was returning 38 without a console.log command , but I added a console.log(empty); after the last command and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for equivalent to your current `for` loop:

```
var len = iAmSoHungry.length;
while(len--) {
    empty.push(iAmSoHungry[len]);
}

console.log(empty);
["Chic Fila", "Pop's Potatoes", "BLT", "Salted Caramel Icecream"]
```

Comment: on each loop iteration, it evaluates the current `len` value and then performs decrement operation right after evaluation. The loop will stop when the value of `len` becomes `0`